# Deleting all records on a table except the latest 10 for each user

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an activities table that has a foreign key reference to a users table. A user can have many activities, and I have a job that will populate their activities on a daily basis. After that job runs, I want to run a SQL query that will delete the oldest records per user and keep the latest 10. This is the schema:

**users**

```
id name
1  Jimmy
2  Johnny
```

**user_activities**

```
id user_id activity date
1  1       foo      2020-08-07 00:00:00
2  1       bar      2020-08-08 00:00:00
3  1       baz      2020-08-09 00:00:00
4  2       foo      2020-08-07 00:00:00
5  2       bar      2020-08-08 00:00:00
6  2       baz      2020-08-09 00:00:00
```

How can I write a query to truncate records up to the latest 10 for each user?

Comment: See "groupwise-max" and "multi-table DELETE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with mysql 5.x and abouve

mysql has since version the window function ROW_NUMBER so that the subquery can be written without user defined variables

I added some data to show that it works

The idea is simple, sort all dates by user_id and keep the 10 newest, the rownumber defines the position of the record sorted by date descending

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_date
>     (`id` int, `user_id` int, `activity` varchar(3), `date` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO user_date
>     (`id`, `user_id`, `activity`, `date`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 'foo', '2020-08-07 00:00:00'),
>     (2, 1, 'bar', '2020-08-08 00:00:00'),
>     (3, 1, 'baz', '2020-08-09 00:00:00'),
>     (4, 2, 'foo', '2020-08-07 00:00:00'),
>     (5, 2, 'bar', '2020-08-08 00:00:00'),
>     (6, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-09 00:00:00')
>     ,
>     (7, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (8, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (9, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (10, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (11, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (12, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (13, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (14, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (15, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (16, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> DELETE u1
> FROM
>        user_date AS u1
>    JOIN
> (
> SELECT  id
>   FROM
>      (
>       SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.user_id,@row_num+1,1) AS 'RowNumber'
>              ,o.id
>              ,@prev_value := o.user_id
>         FROM user_date o,
>              (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
>              (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
>        ORDER BY o.user_id, o.`date` DESC
>      ) subquery
>  WHERE `RowNumber` > 10 ) u2 ON u1.id = u2.id
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_date
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | activity | date               
> -: | ------: | :------- | :------------------
>  1 |       1 | foo      | 2020-08-07 00:00:00
>  2 |       1 | bar      | 2020-08-08 00:00:00
>  3 |       1 | baz      | 2020-08-09 00:00:00
>  7 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
>  8 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
>  9 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 10 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 11 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 12 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 13 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 14 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 15 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 16 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1beba8c3b83d1f300bf3f1938013437)*

For **Sql Server**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_date
>     (id int, user_id int, activity varchar(3), date varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO user_date
>     (id, user_id, activity, date)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 'foo', '2020-08-07 00:00:00'),
>     (2, 1, 'bar', '2020-08-08 00:00:00'),
>     (3, 1, 'baz', '2020-08-09 00:00:00'),
>     (4, 2, 'foo', '2020-08-07 00:00:00'),
>     (5, 2, 'bar', '2020-08-08 00:00:00'),
>     (6, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-09 00:00:00')
>     ,
>     (7, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (8, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (9, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (10, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (11, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (12, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (13, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (14, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (15, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
>     (16, 2, 'baz', '2020-08-10 00:00:00')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DELETE u1
> FROM
>        user_date AS u1
>    JOIN
> (
> SELECT  id
>   FROM
>      (
>       SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.user_id ORDER BY o.[date] DESC) 
>                     AS RowNumber
>              ,o.id
>              ,o.user_id
>         FROM user_date o
>      ) subquery
>  WHERE RowNumber > 10 ) u2 ON u1.id = u2.id  
>  
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_date
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | activity | date               
> -: | ------: | :------- | :------------------
>  1 |       1 | foo      | 2020-08-07 00:00:00
>  2 |       1 | bar      | 2020-08-08 00:00:00
>  3 |       1 | baz      | 2020-08-09 00:00:00
>  7 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
>  8 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
>  9 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 10 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 11 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 12 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 13 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 14 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 15 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> 16 |       2 | baz      | 2020-08-10 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=953649052237e7d766681ad7938a4ab8)*

Comment: might you be able to rewrite the script for SQL server? Thanks.

Comment: @AlGuy I added a sql server version, don't forget to upvote